# DocumentList API resumable upload not working

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Recently it appears that resumable upload is not working. All my requests for upload are returning 500.

Here is the exception stacktrace I receive:

```
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/folder%3A0B6Qc9CKRbiEMNTQ2NWYzMjEtY2EwNC00NzRhLWFjNGQtNGEzNzEzNzc4MTRj/contents/?convert=false&upload_id=AEnB2UpuikBd2Rd1wk1j8BPAI3KKTJ1pWoAJEPm3KZCBqLIqj6Rm9uOy7NezC8dzROUghRpTI6Clblj8j4zhKO91ductHL2LBA
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
        at GoogleDocsManager.uploadWithResumableUpload(GoogleDocsManager.java:1342)
```

This is the code (no changes were made since yesterday (21-11-2012))

```
        String link = initiateSession(mediaBytes, contentType, title, withConvert);

        URL url = new URL(link); 
        HttpURLConnection copyHttpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
        copyHttpUrlConn.setDoOutput(true); 
        copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestMethod("PUT"); 

        copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",contentType);
        copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", mediaBytes.length + "");

        String range = "bytes 0-" + (mediaBytes.length - 1) + "/" + (mediaBytes.length);

        copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Range", range);

        OutputStream outputStream = copyHttpUrlConn.getOutputStream(); 

        outputStream.write(mediaBytes);

        System.out.println("Code: " + copyHttpUrlConn.getResponseCode());// here I receive the exception
```

Now I really don't know where to write this kind of posts... From the old DocumentList Api group I was redirected here.

I hope that this issue is fixed soon (I have 2 different programs which use this resumable upload and yesterday both were ok, so I guess that this problem is not on my side)

Best regards,

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I can upload files from the Drive interface, but my API requests are being cut off (500 error). Is there  an official post somewhere regarding this issue ?

Comment: Hi @ice13ill , are you also using documentlist api? Or this problem exists also with drive sdk?

Answer (score 0):

500 errors in the Drive SDK are a way of life. I get them around 0.5% of the time. Try wrapping your API calls in an exponential backoff and retry.

Because your error is on an upload, you might want to verify that the file you're uploading has valid contents according to its mime type. (eg. if it's text/html, does the file contain valid html).

Comment: The problems probably appeared as if from nowhere (as in my case too), without any modifications to the code.

Comment: Hi @pinoyyid , I receive 500 at every request. I am using documentlist api (not drive sdk) and I have the same code that 2 days ago worked. I am sure that this is not an error on my side.

Answer (score 0):

After 4 days the errors stopped (with no changes made to the code).
PS: For a period there were a strange behaviour (on google appengine not working, and localhost yes).